# Mixing business and pleasure

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

I asked my manager if it was okay for my friends to come hang around at the shop. Here's his answer:

> As I've said, they're always very welcome. But can I just remind that we'll keep working? Clients come first, your friends must naturally respect that. Did I mention things move quickly 'round the warehouse? Every hand is needed in there this time. Forget not our owner's order: "remember shop's slogan".

What is our slogan?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Always keep your things in order?

**Reason:**

> Could be a red herring, but the words in every sentence are ordered alphabetically except for those six.

Comment: Well, that didn't take long! :P Yeah, this is the answer.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how you managed that..

Comment: @Pogrindis Basically I noticed very quickly that rot13(gur svefg yrggre bs rnpu fragrapr jnf nopqrs).  And well... rot13(ybbxvat ng gur svefg yrggre bs rnpu jbeq vf cerggl zhpu fgnaqneq cenpgvpr nebhaq urer, fb V ernyvmrq jung jnf tbvat ba dhvgr snfg) :)

Comment: rot13("ybbxvat ng gur svefg yrggre bs rnpu jbeq vf cerggl zhpu fgnaqneq cenpgvpr nebhaq urer" naq abj V yrnea fbzrguvat arj!) ++